# How can we access the Inbox Monitor API function to start receiving reports of the raw data?

Tags: api

We found some documentation within ExactTarget (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/inbox_tools/) that mentions that an API exists with the Inbox Monitor section (where the inbox placement rates are located), but it states that we would need to contact an account manager to be able to access it:

> You may prefer raw data to the data in the user interface. Through the API function, you can
>   request specific sets of data using XML/RPC (remote procedure call). Contact an Account
>   Manager if you wish to receive reports of this raw data.
>   Examples of data sent using the API function:
>
> - Lists of From domains for a given realm (account).
> - Overall aggregated statistical data (inbox %, bulk %, missing %) for campaign(s).
> - Overall statistical data by ISP for a campaign.
> - Detailed mailbox provider seed placement data on a per campaign basis.

We've tried reaching out to Platinum Support and our ET Account Manager, but they were not familiar with the API and suggested that we try asking in this forum.  Is anyone able to give more information on how to utilize this API/receive the reports of the raw Inbox Monitor data?